# How to read total number of argument passed with a shell script and assign it to a variable

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I want to run a shell script with some arguments passed with it, number of argument will be keep on changing, I want to first read the total number of argument passed then read each one and store those arguments in the variables with the help of “for” or “while” loop, I am doing as below but not getting the argument assigned into the variables

running script as below
sh My_script.sh ARG1 ARG2 ARG3 ... ARGn

I tried to write as below

```
#!/bin/bash
TOTAL_ARG=$#
NEW_PATH=""
n=1
While [[ $n -le $TOTAL_ARG ]]
do
  CUS_PATH=""
  CUS_PATH="$`echo $n`"
  NEW_PATH="$WORSPACE"/"$CUS_PATH"" "
  echo $NEW_PATH
  n=$((n+1))
done
```

Looks like CUS_PATH="$`echo $n`" line is not able to execute and produce the value of $1 $2 $3 $4 ...$n

Comment: You should explain what you are trying to get (desired output) and what you are getting (actual output).

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer for first version of question:

All that looping is unnecessary.  Your code can reduce to:

```
#!/bin/bash
new_path="$*"
echo "new_path is '$new_path'"
```

Running it, for example, on your argument list:

```
$ bash My_script.sh ARG1 ARG2 ARG3 ... ARGn
new_path is 'ARG1 ARG2 ARG3 ... ARGn'
```

If you really want to access an argument by the number in variable `n` (this is rarely needed):

```
#!/bin/bash
new_path="$*"
echo "new_path is '$new_path'"
n=3
echo "Argument #$n is '${!n}'"
```

As an example:

```
$ bash My_script.sh ARG1 ARG2 ARG3 ... ARGn
new_path is 'ARG1 ARG2 ARG3 ... ARGn'
Argument #3 is 'ARG3'
```

#### Answer for second version of question

Try:

```
$ cat My_script.sh 
#!/bin/bash
workspace=/abc/def
for x in "$@"
do
    new_path="$new_path $workspace/$x"
done
echo "new_path is '$new_path'"
```

For example:

```
$ bash My_script.sh ARG1 ARG2 ARG3 ... ARGn
new_path is ' /abc/def/ARG1 /abc/def/ARG2 /abc/def/ARG3 /abc/def/... /abc/def/ARGn'
```

**Alternatively:**

```
$ cat My_script.sh 
#!/bin/bash
workspace=/abc/def
new_path=" $*"
new_path=${new_path// / $workspace/}
echo "new_path is '$new_path'"

$ bash My_script.sh ARG1 ARG2 ARG3 ... ARGn
new_path is ' /abc/def/ARG1 /abc/def/ARG2 /abc/def/ARG3 /abc/def/... /abc/def/ARGn'
```

Comment: Thanks John!!   I missed to mention that new_path will have the value after adding path of $WORKSPACE with each argument, So I may not use new_path="$*"

Comment: @SaurabhSuman See updated answer for method to prepend workspace to each argument.

Comment: I am facing one more issue it is some thing like below CUST_PATH="src libs/*.jar"  then while executing script bash My_script.sh $CUST_PATH. but issue is here it is expending libs/*.jar and it is complaining like too many argumnet ...so how to stop the lib/*.jar to get expended

Comment: Double quotes will stop pathname expansion: `My_script.sh "$CUST_PATH"`

Comment: Looks My_script.sh "$CUST_PATH"  is not help here as it is getting excuted as follow  My_script.sh 'src libs/*.jar' as a result count of parameter become 1 only